# MySQL if/else for tables

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to if else tables in mysql?

Example:

```
select * from tableA A, if(tableA.find=1,TableBA B,TableBB B) where A.id = B.aid
```

Real Example:

tables are: `location_order`, `order_contract`, `order_gm`, `order_gm_hh`:

```
select * 
from   location order lo, order_contract oc, if(lo.hh=0,order_gm,order_gm_hh) as og 
where  lo.orderid = oc.orderid && oc.gmid = og.id
```

Comment: Sounds like you have some serious normalization problems if your foreign key links to multiple tables based on a value in tableA.

Comment: The problem is I have one table which defines an order and two different tables for calculations. Depending on a field in the order is which table and set of code I use but I need to be able to run a summary of both at the same time. Another question with the basic same question; just forgot until i posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924632/mysql-select-from-different-table-depending-on-master-table

Comment: Could you put realistic table names in your example to demonstrate? The comment is a little hard to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [left outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) both tables, and then use the [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT     a.*,
           IF(a.find = 1, b1.value, b2.value) b_value
FROM       tableA a
LEFT JOIN  tableBA b1 ON (b1.aid = a.id)
LEFT JOIN  tableBB b2 ON (b2.aid = a.id);
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (id int, find int, value int);
CREATE TABLE tableBA (id int, aid int, value int);
CREATE TABLE tableBB (id int, aid int, value int);

INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (1, 1, 100);
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (2, 0, 200);
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (3, 1, 300);
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (4, 0, 400);

INSERT INTO tableBA VALUES (1, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO tableBA VALUES (2, 3, 20);

INSERT INTO tableBB VALUES (1, 2, 30);
INSERT INTO tableBB VALUES (2, 4, 40);
```

Result:

```
+------+------+-------+---------+
| id   | find | value | b_value |
+------+------+-------+---------+
|    1 |    0 |   100 |      10 |
|    2 |    1 |   200 |      30 |
|    3 |    0 |   300 |      20 |
|    4 |    1 |   400 |      40 |
+------+------+-------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This takes way too long to find the results. The tables have 1000s and eventually 10k to 100k of records. Thanks that does give me a couple ideas.

Comment: @David: Do you have an index on the `aid` columns in the tables `tableBA` and `tableBA`? This shouldn't be that slow, even will 100ks of rows, if properly indexed.

Comment: I do running some more test now

Answer (score 0):

You could have to separate this out into two select statements. For example:

```
select * from tableA A
inner join TableBA B on A.id = B.aid
where A.find = 1

UNION 

select * from tableA A
inner join TableBB B on A.id = B.aid
where A.find <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an outer join on both tables and use a case statement in the select to pull the value from whichever table meets the Find=1 criteria using a case statement.

```
SELECT     Case A.Find 
              WHEN 1 THEN B1.SomeField 
              ELSE B2.SomeField 
           END as SomeField
FROM       tableA A
LEFT JOIN  tableBA b1 ON (b1.aid = A.id)
LEFT JOIN  tableBB b2 ON (b2.aid = A.id);
```